# Erro de localização do ponto de entrada no MYSQL

Tags: mysql

O que poderia ser esse erro?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei de tudo e nao consegui resolvê-lo...

Comment: precisa de fornecer mais detalhes, que passos realizou até aparecer esse erro?

Comment: Apenas abri o front e apareceu o erro, fora este erro, não consigo me conectar com meus bancos.

Comment: bom, desculpe pelo o que eu falei aí, mas, uma pergunta, aonde a imagem é a resposta, e logo em cima tem o nome do erro e aonde é o erro, não preciso dar um contexto aonde a img é o próprio contexto, e a tag é a relação do erro. '-'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ao que parece, `mysqlfront.exe` está à procura de um procedimento `mysql_drop_db` que está deprecado e não existe na sua biblioteca actual de MySQL.

Vá a uma biblioteca de `dll's`, procure uma versão anterior de `libmySQL.dll` que contenha o procedimento `mysql_drop_db` e substitua (sem perder o original).

Se isso não resolver, experimente instalar outro IDE de MySQL que foi desenvolvido directamente pela equipa da Oracle e que da minha experiência funciona perfeitamente para todo o tipo de projectos e problemas:
[MySQL WorkBench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)

Comment: Consegui resolver versão, como vc disse, procurei uma versão mais atual do libmysql, e reinstalei o mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Pode ser versão errada da DLL ou que não está achando a versão correta dela (talvez possa ter outros motivos também). Verifique essas duas coisas. A dll está em c:\windows\system32?

Comment: Ja verifiquei, e está lá!

Comment: E quanto ao "versão errada da DLL"? Conferiu também?